# Cancellation of elements in the Gromov boundary of a finitely generated free group

Tags: group-theory, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

This question is inspired by [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448049) from **MO**

Let $A$ be a finite set of free generators and their inverses and $F$ the free group generated by elements in $A$ (some call $A$ the **alphabet** of $F$). For each $g\in F$, use $\vert\,g\,\vert$ to denote the length of $g$. The [**Gromov boundary**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov_boundary) of $F$, denoted by $\partial F$, can be viewed as the set of words that consists of letters from $A$ and has infinite length starting from the left. For instance, $a_1 a_2 \cdots $ is the general form of elements in $\partial F$ where $a_i\in A$ and $a_i a_{i+1}\neq e$ for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$.

Set $\overline{F} = F\cup\partial F$. Given $x, y\in\overline{F}$, if $x\neq y$, let $x\wedge y$ denote the common part between $x$ and $y$ starting from the left. For instance: $ (a_1 \cdots a_n )\wedge (a_1 \cdots a_n b_{n+1} b_{n+2} \cdots) = a_1 \cdots a_n$. Define a function $d: \overline{F}\times\overline{F}\rightarrow(0, 1)$ as follows: $d(x, y)=0$ if $x=y$ and $d(x, y)= \operatorname{exp}(-\vert\,x\wedge\,y\,\vert)$. One can check $(\overline{F}, d)$ is a compact metric space and $d$ is an ultrametric. From now on, we assume $\overline{F}$ is equipped with the $d$-metric topology. An action of $F$ on $\partial F$ can be defined as follows: given $g\in F$ and $x\in\partial F$, $g\cdot x = gx$ (after cancellation).

Given $\gamma\in\partial F$, for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$, let $\gamma_i$ denote the $i$-th letter of $\gamma$ and define $[\gamma]_i = \gamma_1 \cdots \gamma_i$. Obviously, for each $\gamma\in\partial F$, we have $\gamma = \lim_i [\gamma]_i$. From now on we only consider $\gamma\in\partial F$ such that $\gamma \neq \lim_n gh^n$ for any $g, h\in F$. Then define:

$$
C_{\gamma} = \overline{ \big\{ [\gamma]_n^{-1} \big\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} } \cap\partial F
$$

which is the set of clustered points of the sequence $\big\{ [\gamma]_n^{-1} \big\}$ and, by compactness of $\overline{F}$, is non-empty. My question are:

1. Is $C_{\gamma}$ countable regardless of the choice of $\gamma$? If not, is the set $\big\{ \gamma\in\partial F \,\vert\, C_{\gamma} \text{  uncountable  } \big\}$ countable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of questions in your post, each one of them being quite substantial. Let me suggest, again, [one question per post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#33671) please. I'll answer your first question.

In fact there is an example where $C_\gamma = \partial F$, and so no, $C_\gamma$ need not be countable.

To describe the example, start with a list of the reduced words representing all nontrivial elements of $F$:
$$\delta_1, \delta_2, \delta_3, ...
$$
Let's choose them so that $\delta_{i} \delta_{i+1}$ has no cancellations, for all $i \ge 1$. I believe this is possible, with a little care.

Define $\gamma$ to be the infinite concatenation of these elements:
$$\gamma = \delta_1 \delta_2 \delta_3 \cdots
$$
The sequence $[\gamma]_n^{-1}$ contains the following subsequence:
$$\underbrace{\delta_1^{-1}}_{\theta_1} \quad \underbrace{\delta_2^{-1}\delta_1^{-1}}_{\theta_2} \quad \underbrace{\delta_3^{-1}\delta_2^{-1}\delta_1^{-1}}_{\theta_2} \quad \cdots 
$$
Notice that the sequence $\delta_1^{-1}$, $\delta_2^{-2}$, $\delta_3^{-3}$ also lists the reduced words representing all nontrivial elements of $F$.

From this it follows that the set $C_\gamma$ contains every element of $\partial F$. To prove this, consider any element of $\partial F$ write it as an infinite word $a_1a_2a_3...$ with no cancellation. Each initial segment $a_1a_2a_3...a_i$ is equal to some $\delta_{n_i}^{-1}$, and so the sequence $\theta_{n_1},\theta_{n_2},\theta_{n_3},...$ converges to $a_1a_2a_3...$.

I believe that one can tailor this method to show that for ***every*** closed subset $C \subset \partial F$ there exists a $\gamma$ such that $C=C_\gamma$. It would be quite a bit trickier to carefully choose the appropriate list $\delta_1,\delta_2,\delta_3$,..., but this should be possible.

This gives a very strongly negative answer to the sub-question of your first question: there are uncountably many uncountable closed subsets of $\partial F$, so the set $\{\gamma \mid C_\gamma \, \text{is uncountable}\}$ is uncountable (that was a hard sentence to write! ... and, a day later, I realized that a missed one "uncountable").

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! From now on I will only include one question per post since I was afraid that I was not allowed to ask different questions under the same context.