# Weak convergence of measures on the Gromov boundary of a finitely generated free group

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, geometric-group-theory

In the set-up of [my previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4713932), let $\theta$ be a purely non-atomic finite regular measure defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the metric space $(\partial F, d)$. We say **$\theta$ admits a $\epsilon$-partition** if there exists a measurable finite partition $\{A_i\}_{i\leq N}$ of $\partial F$ such that $\theta(A_i) < \epsilon$ for each $i\leq N$. According to [Michael's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/641727/507302), for each $\epsilon\in(0, 1)$, $\theta$ admits a $\epsilon$-partition of $\partial F$. Since $\theta$ is regular, each $\epsilon$-partition can induce an finite open cover where each set has $\theta$-measure strictly less than $\epsilon$.

Then, given a sequence $\{g_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq F$ that converges to $\xi\in\partial F$, I am tempted to prove that $g_n\theta$ converges to the dirac measure $\delta_{\xi}$ weakly (where, for each Borel subset $O\subseteq\partial F$, $g_n\theta(O) = \theta(g_n^{-1}O)$). For the definition of weak convergence, check this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures). Below is my attempt but, because of the list of equivalence under the **Portmanteau's Theorem** (in the wiki link above), it is wrong and I wonder if anyone could point out my mistakes.

For each $g = g_1 \cdots g_n \in F$, define:

$$
C_g = \big\{ x\in\partial F\,\vert\, x_1 = g_1, \cdots, x_n = g_n \big\}
$$
Since $\partial F$ is totally bounded and $d$ is an ultra-metric, for each open $O\subseteq\partial F$ and $\epsilon\in(0, 1)$, we can find $\{g_i\}_{i\leq K}\subseteq F$ such that $O = \overset{\bullet}{\bigcup}_{i\leq K} C_{g_i}$ (a disjoint union) with $\operatorname{exp}\big( -\vert\,g_i\,\,\vert\big) < \epsilon$ for each $i\leq K$. Hence:

$$
O^c = \bigcap_{i\leq K}C_{g_i}^c = \bigcap_{i\leq K} \Big( \overset{\bullet}{\bigcup}_{\substack{g\in F\backslash\{g_i\} \\ \vert\,g\,\vert = \vert\,g_i\vert}} C_g\Big)
$$
which implies that each closed set can be written as a finite disjoint union of sets of the form $C_h$.

Then I claim:

$$
\forall\,\epsilon\in(0, 1)\, \exists\,N_{\epsilon}\in\mathbb{N} \text{  such that  } \forall\,h\in F, \hspace{0.3cm} \vert\,h\,\vert \geq N_{\epsilon} \hspace{0.3cm}\implies\hspace{0.3cm} \theta(C_h)<\epsilon
$$
Fix $\epsilon\in(0, 1)$ and let $\{O_i\}_{i\leq L}$ be an open cover of $\partial F$ such that $\theta(O_i) <\epsilon$ for each $i\leq L$. Then there exists $\{h_i\}_{i\leq K}\subseteq F$ such that $\{C_{h_i}\}_{i\leq K}$ is a refinement of the cover $\{O_i\}_{i\leq L}$ so that $\theta(C_{h_i})<\epsilon$ for each $i\leq K$. Set $N_{\epsilon} = \max_{i\leq K}\vert\,h_i\,\vert$. Then for each $\gamma\in\partial F$, if $\gamma\in C_{h_i}$, for each $n\geq N_{\epsilon}$ we have $B(\gamma, e^{-n}) = C_{[\gamma]_n} \subseteq C_{h_i}$. Therefore $\theta(C_{[\gamma]_n}) < \epsilon$. Since for each $g\in F$ with $\vert\,g\,\vert\geq N_{\epsilon}$, we can find $\xi\in\partial F$ with $[\xi]_{\vert\,g\,\vert} = g$, the desired result follows (?)

If the proof above (or the statement I claim) is correct, then for each $h\in F$, we have $\limsup_n g_n\theta(C_h) = 0$ because the length of $g_n^{-1}h$ will become arbitrarily large, which shows that for each closed subset $B\subseteq\partial F$, $\limsup_n g_n\theta(B) = 0\leq \delta_{\xi}(B)$. Then we will have $g_n\theta$ converges to $\delta_{\xi}$ weakly, which implies that $\liminf_n g_n\theta(C_h)\geq \delta_{\xi}(C_h)$ for each $h\in F$ since $C_h$ is open. However, this is obviously wrong because $\liminf_n g_n\theta(C_h)=0$ for each $h\in F$.